# How to stretch flex child to fill height of the container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to stretch yellow child to fill all height of parent. Without setting parent height. Height of parent should be dependent on blue child text.
    https://jsfiddle.net/7vaequ1c/1/

```html
<div style='display: flex'>
  <div style='background-color: yellow;height: 100%; width: 20px'>
  </div>
  <div style='background-color: blue'>
  some<br>
  cool<br>
  text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 138, accepted):

When using Flexbox, the major mistake is to start using `height: 100%` all over.

We are used to that in many cases, though when it comes to Flexbox, it often breaks it instead.

*One reason it often breaks when using `height: 100%`, is that the element's parent (parent of the element one want to stretch), need a set height in one way or the other, which flexbox doesn't when not using it.*

*Another reason is, when there is children above and/or below, using 100% on one of those children, it will not take the other children into account, and again often break.*

The solution is simple, just remove the `height: 100%`, and it will work automatically.

The reason it does, is for *flex item* in *row* direction (the default), the `align-items` control the vertical behavior, and as its default is `stretch` this just work as is.

Stack snippet

```html
<div style='display: flex'>
  <div style='background-color: yellow; width: 20px'>
  </div>
  <div style='background-color: blue'>
    some<br> cool<br> text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why does adding `height: 100%` break it?

Comment: @cib In this case `height: 100%` could work, though for it actually do, the child's parent need an explicit set height. Now, as the parent doesn't have that, a Flexbox row (direction) child's _height_ is controlled with `align-items`, and as it defaults to `stretch` it simply will fill the parents height. What I meant with _it often breaks it instead_ is, when there is children above and below, using 100% on a child in the middle will not take the other children into account, hence it could break.

Comment: hero. I was 100%ing all over the place, removing it worked.

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: This answer does not work in every case and it fails to explain its assumptions about height: 100% breaking the intended layout.

Comment: @IngoSteinke -- It was not an assumption, it will break when certain conditions aren't met. I added a couple of cases where it will. And of course, no given layout is guaranteed to work, depending on how it is constructed, hence one need to read up on how flexbox actually works.

Answer (score 14):

If I understood correctly, you are looking for the `align-items` property, which defines the layout along the cross axis, in this case vertically.

You can find a good overview here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch; // <-- stretch vertical (default value, can be omitted here)
  align-content: center;
}

.box {
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1em;
}

.box--yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.box--blue {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="box box--yellow">
    yellow
  </div>
  <div class="box box--blue">
    some<br>
    cool<br>
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `align-items: stretch;` is the default so adding that property:value won't make a difference.

Comment: @LGSon True. I just wanted to point out the property that is responsible for the stretching. Clearly I should have mentioned that it is the default behaviour!

Answer (score 4):

Remove

> height:100%;

and instead do something like this example :

```
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column">
<div style="flex-grow:1;"> Item 1 </div>
<div style="flex-grow:1;"> Item 2 </div>
</div>
```

above example will show you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly pertaining to OP's example, but if you want to get the flex child to grow in the vertical direction, use `flex-grow: 1` on the child. In the image, the parent has `display:flex` and `flex-direction: column`.

[image]

Answer (score -5):

Here you go:

```html
<div style='display: flex;'>
  <div style='background-color: yellow; flex: none auto; width: 20px'></div>
  <div style='background-color: blue'>
    some<br>
    cool<br>
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No explanation is a bad answer, and you also have syntax error. I suggest you read up on Flexbox before answer questions using it.