# How to make a flex element fully expand to fill the containing element?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here is my code.

I want the element `.container` to fully expand and occupy the area of `.toplevel`.

```css
.toplevel {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 800px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  border: solid 1px red;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  // min-height: 800px;
}

.up {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.down {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="toplevel">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="up">
      This is up
    </div>
    <div class="up">
      This is down
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However it seems like the only way to make the `.container` larger height-wise is to define a `min-height`. It is too inflexible because I will have provide a different value for different device form factor.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46954952/how-to-stretch-flex-child-to-fill-height-of-the-container/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simpy add `display: flex` to `.toplevel` and remove `height: 100%` from `.container`.

This work based on the fact that flex row item's height behavior can be controlled with the `align-items` property. As it by default has `stretch`, it will fill its parents height.

As a note, in general, when it comes to Flexbox, it is preferable to make use of its own properties instead of `height`/`width`. By doing so you also get a better cross browser support.

Stack snippet

```css
.toplevel {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 800px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  display: flex;              /* added  */
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  border: solid 1px red;
  /*height: 100%;                removed  */
  flex: 1 1 auto;            /*  changed, flex row item need the grow value
                                          to be 1 to fill its parent's width  */
  flex-direction: column;
}

.up {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.down {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="toplevel">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="up">
      This is up
    </div>
    <div class="down">
      This is down
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think you have to add direction column to toplevel too :)

Comment: in the OP code the inner divs are taking full width and like what you did it's not the case ... they are stretched to full height but not full width

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ok, I focused on the _height_ issue...thanks for the note, updated.

Answer (score 2):

Make toplevel `display:flex` also with column direction and then add `flex:1` to container :

*I suppose you made a mistake in the code as you added two `up` divs so I corrected*

```css
.toplevel {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 800px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  border: solid 1px red;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.up {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.down {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="toplevel">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="up">
      This is up
    </div>
    <div class="down">
      This is down
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To use percentage height, you need all parents to have a set height. In your case `.toplevel` parent `body`, doesn't have height, so `.toplevel` height of `100%` doesn't work, and it causes the `.container` height to fail as well.
A simple solution is to set the `.toplevel` height using `vh` units instead of percentage:

```css
.toplevel {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 800px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  border: solid 1px red;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  // min-height: 800px;
}

.up {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.down {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="toplevel">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="up">
      This is up
    </div>
    <div class="up">
      This is down
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse the `height` and `min-height` of the `.toplevel`:

```css
.toplevel {
  height: 800px;
  min-height: 100%;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  border: solid 1px red;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*min-height: 800px;*/
}

.up {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.down {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="toplevel">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="up">
      This is up
    </div>
    <div class="up">
      This is down
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```