# Same Height Cards in Material UI

Tags: css, material-ui

Trying to have 3 horizontal cards but with the same height and to be responsive.

Like

Card A | Card B | Card C

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add following properties to your `Card`

```
.MuiCard-root.same-height {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

and it will add the necessary space between `CardContent` and `CardActions`

Same question was answered here: [How to make Material-UI CardActions always stick to the bottom of parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57818778/how-to-make-material-ui-cardactions-always-stick-to-the-bottom-of-parent)

Answer (score 36):

Overriding the rendering component of `<Grid item />` with `<Card>` as suggested in the answers above messes up the spacings (the `spacing` prop of `<Grid container />` stops working). Please, see my explanation below about how you can achieve the vertical alignment of cards without unwanted side effects.

**Setting `display: 'flex'` on `<Grid item />` should be enough to align the heights of all `<Card />` elements.**

However, for additional effect of nicely stretching `<CardContent>` and `<CardActions>` vertically, set `display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between', flexDirection: 'column'` on the `<Card />` element as well.

```
<Grid container alignItems="stretch">
  <Grid item style={{display: 'flex'}}>
    <Card style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between', flexDirection: 'column'}}>
      // contents of your Card
    <Card/>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item style={{display: 'flex'}}>
    <Card style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between', flexDirection: 'column'}}>
      // contents of your Card
    <Card/>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Looks like this approach also breaks `xs={6}` or similar on `Grid item`

Comment: Although `width: 100%` on the `Card` fixes that.

Comment: This works as expected with the comment from @StaffordWilliams !

Comment: This works as expected on the heights. However, I noticed that the width of the cards are no longer the full grid width. Any idea why?

Answer (score 31):

You can use the Grid component to achieve this:

```
<Grid container alignItems="stretch">

  <Grid item component={Card} xs>
    <CardContent>
       // Card A content
    </CardContent>
    <CardActions>
      // Card A actions
    </CardActions>
  </Grid>

  <Grid item component={Card} xs>
    <CardContent>
      // Card B content
    </CardContent>
    <CardActions>
      // Card B actions
    </CardActions>
  </Grid>

  <Grid item component={Card} xs>
    <CardContent>
      // Card B content
    </CardContent>
    <CardActions>
      // Card B actions
    </CardActions>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

`alignItems="stretch"` (Which you don't actually need to specify, since stretch is the default) will have the effect of stretching the height of each item when the flex direction is `row` (which is also the default direction).  You can see this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46956430/253693

The `xs` attribute on each `Grid item` takes advantage of [auto-layout](https://material-ui.com/layout/grid/#auto-layout), instructing each card to equally share the available width.

There are a few more clean-up items you could address, namely by using the [withStyles HOC](https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#withstyles-styles-options-higher-order-component) to apply a class to each Card component that fixes spacing and ensure that the CardActions remain at the bottom of the card, regardless of the height of the CardContent:

```
const styles = {
  card: {
    // Provide some spacing between cards
    margin: 16,

    // Use flex layout with column direction for components in the card
    // (CardContent and CardActions)
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",

    // Justify the content so that CardContent will always be at the top of the card,
    // and CardActions will be at the bottom
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  }
};
```

You would then apply these styles to each card like so:

```
<Grid item component={Card} xs className={classes.card}>
```

Here's a working example that brings everything together: https://codesandbox.io/embed/r9y95vr5n

Comment: I want to control the width of each grid item using `xs={whatever}`. However when I do that, items do not spread over the entire row because of the margin (e.g. 2 grid items with `xs={6}`will show up on two different rows). If I remove the margin, the cards are touching each other. Usually I manage this with the `spacing` prop in the grid container but it doesn't change anything. How would you adapt your answer for a manual layout?

Comment: @7hibault, I faced the same issue. Unfortunately, overriding the rendering component of `<Grid item />` with `<Card>` messes up the spacings as you noticed. Please, see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59470890/1491042) about how the vertical alignment of cards can be achieved without unwanted side effects.

Answer (score 8):

I think that a easier way:

https://github.com/creativetimofficial/ct-material-dashboard-pro-react/issues/45#issuecomment-442885173

```
import React from "react"
import { Card, CardBody, CardFooter } from "components"

import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles"

const styles = {
fullHeightCard: {
    height: "100%",
    },
}

const Item = (props) => {
    const {classes} = props

    // 1-5 paragraphs to create card height variance
    let paragraphs = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(5))

    return (
        <Card className={classes.fullHeightCard}>
            <CardBody>
                {Array(paragraphs).fill().map((_,i) => (
                    <p>{i+1}</p>
                ))}
            </CardBody>
            <CardFooter>
            {'Footer content'}
            </CardFooter>
        </Card>
    )
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Item)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this working with an even simpler solution: setting `display: grid` on the parent grid.

```jsx
<Grid container style={{ display: 'grid' }}>
  <Grid item>
    <Card>
      // contents of your Card
    <Card />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item>
    <Card>
      // contents of your Card
    <Card />
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: perfect thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clean solution.

```
<Card sx={{height: 100%}}>
```