# How to make Material-UI CardActions always stick to the bottom of parent

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The blue CardActions section of the 2nd Material-UI card is not staying at the bottom which makes the page looks not concise.

I already tried to set the height to 100% for CardContent but nothing has changed.

I created a sandbox for illustration of the problem:

https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-glitter-7vyep

I would like that the Material-UI CardAction stays always at the bottom of the container, no matter how many items I have in the CardContent.

Comment: please check below answer !

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you have to add following properties to `.MuiCard-root`

```
.MuiCard-root{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

[image]

```
Other Method is :

.MuiCard-root{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.MuiCardActions-root{
   margin-top: auto;
}
```

Comment: They should consider making this part of the library.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and the accepted answer partly solved the problem but definitely put me on the right track. This solution's problem is that other card components are moved around. In my case I got a space between the header and an image at the top of the card due to the space-between.

So on the card root I did:

```
<Card sx={{ 
    height: "100%",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
  }}>
```

And then on the CardActions I did:

```
<CardActions disableSpacing sx={{ mt: "auto" }}>
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer will center the content within the card.  This often leads to undesirable alignment problems.  If instead you'd like the CardContent to maintain the normal spacing below the CardHeader, and "push" the Actions to the bottom of the card, this way works better.

#### The CSS

```
.MuiCard-root{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

#### The Card

```
<Card>
    <CardHeader>...</CardHeader>
    <CardContent>...></CardContent>
    <div className={"flex-grow"} />
    <CardActions>...</CardActions>
</Card>
```

Note that this example makes use of tailwindcss with the "flex-grow" property.  If you aren't using tailwind, simply make sure the div has `flex-grow:1` applied to it.