# Inner div has height bigger than container

Tags: html, reactjs, css, flexbox

I have a problem of footer being in the middle of my main area.

By default it looks like this:

```
<div style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', display: 'flex', flexFlow: 'column nowrap'}}>
    <div id="appbar"></div>
    <div id="main" style={{ margin: '4.5rem 0 0 0', width: '100%', height: '100%', boxSizing: 'border-box' }}>
        <Router>
            <Home />
        </Router>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

What happens is main div set to 100% which is expected, but then it some some deeply nested child (Home component) which has height of more than 100% of the original height. And after that my footer happens to stuck in the middle of main:[image]

How can I overcome that issue?

Comment: Have a look here, as I think it explains it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46954952/how-to-stretch-flex-child-to-fill-height-of-the-container/46956430#46956430

Comment: Your main issue is setting the `main` element to `height: 100%`, which make flex not work properly. For the `main` to fill the remaining it needs `flex: 1` instead of a height.

Comment: Thank you guys! But how then could I setup so somewhere deep, I want my component to be 100% height? Basically I use react-virtualized and I want with as little effort as possible set height value to be of visible screen height?

Comment: oh wow! @LGSon setting flex instead of height really helped. Basically I have ended up with flex: '1 0 80%' for the main area and it works as expected. If you make an answer I will accept it as the proper solution one!

Comment: Then its answered already...so linked to it instead.

Answer (score -1):

Try to give an absolute position with bottom 0 and give padding bottom for your content

Comment: Please show some code example