# Can not set flexbox children height to 100% in Chrome

Tags: html, css, flexbox, height

I am trying to make the blue box below fill the entire height of the button, but it doesn't seem to work. Why doesn't `height: 100%` work for the `.el` element?

```css
button {
  background: red;
  height: 55px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.el {
  display: block;
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span class="el">
    Content
  </span>
  Other
</button>
```

Output (Chrome 76): [image]

**Other browsers seem to show the expected result**:
Edge: [image]
Firefox: [image]

Comment: Have you tried running this code snippet in this StackOverflow page ? The blue span does fill the entire height of the button.

Comment: @anjanesh It doesn't for me (in Chrome 76), I will post a screenshot. I tried it, and in Firefox it seems to work correctly.

Comment: Not all tags can/like to be displayed as `flex`. Check dupe link.

Comment: And btw, don't use `height: 100%` (or any other value) on flex children. They (when in row direction, which also is the default) generally fill their parent out of the box: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46954952/how-to-stretch-flex-child-to-fill-height-of-the-container/46956430#46956430

Comment: Also, changing flex childrens display type has no effect, they display/behave _block like_.

Comment: If you need to use a `button`, this CSS will give the expected result: `button {
  background: red;
  height: 55px;
}

.el {
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle
}`

Comment: @LGSon Thanks for the comments, the issue was that I already had the HTML and CSS there for a lot of different elements, so I wanted a quick fix for this specific button without changing too much of the CSS. I actually ended up using an exact value in pixels for the height, as that was the fastest way to solve this specific problem.

Comment: @LGSon I can not use `vertical-align-middle` as there are several other elements inside that button that rely on the flexbox `align-items: center;` style.

Comment: Well, then that should have been stated in the question. As the dupe says, a `button` can't be a flex parent (yet, cross browser), simply add another `span` as a main wrapper and make it `display: flex`. And do note, if some flex children should fill parent, some vertically center, you need to use `align-self` on their styles, e.g. `align-self: stretch` if `align-items: center` is use in parent style

Comment: I was afraid to change any HTML as it might affect many other components. I did not know about button not being able to be a flex parent, I find it a bit strange and not intuitive, as I expected it to act as any other DOM node.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
.el {
  display: block;
  background: blue;
  height: inherit;
}
```

Comment: `height: inherit;` Does make the blue div larger in height, but it makes it too big (probably same height as the button including the paddings, so it overflows the button).

Comment: it sets height same as wrapper, your wrapper contains padding/margin/border as well so it's natural that `height: inherit` will make child to look larger than wrapper

Comment: basic mathematics

Comment: I understand that, but it's not the desired outcome (I am not the downvoter though)