# Restrict element height to content, and maintain collapsed overflow

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a pop-up modal which works overall, however the one annoyance is it has a hardcoded `max-height` which I'd like to eliminate.

**Option #1:**
Initially I explored using `height: auto` on the modal, which does keep the modal height to the natural height of the contents. However this effects the collapsing of the modal when you scale the browser viewport to a short height. **The modal overflows out of the viewport, instead of only the green image area overflowing.**

**Option #2:** I'm aware of the possibility of `max-content` (for `height`... or even `max-height` ?) but I haven't been able to get it to work anywhere, and anyhow it has spotty browser support.

**Option #3 (current):** Setting the modal to `height: 100%` and `max-height: 500px` is good enough, however obviously the content needs to be shorter than that.

Overall, requirements are:

A - In small screens, the modal should collapse with the green image area overflowing, thereby maintaining modal title and buttons in view.

B - In large screens, the modal height should only be as big as the contents.

C - Whatever happens, the modal should never visibly go past the global padding (2em).

See `#modal` in CSS below:

[Demo and code here (Codepen)](https://codepen.io/MarsAndBack/pen/vYyWVZg)

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#app {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 2em;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
}

#modal { 
  /* OPTION #1 */
  /* FAILS in small screen: overflow of green image not invoked */
  /* height: auto; */
  
  /* OPTION #2 */
  /* Not working? */
  /* height: max-content; */
  
  /* OPTION #3 */
  /* WORKS but specifying a max-height is not ideal */
  height: 100%;  
  max-height: 500px;  

  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: pink; 
  overflow: hidden;
}

#modal_inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#image {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  flex: 1;
}

#image .inner {
  background-color: lime;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

#controls {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 20em;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

#cta {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 10em;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  
  <div id="container">
    <div id="modal">
      <div id="modal_inner">
          <div id="title">TITLE</div>
          <div id="image"> 
            <div class="inner">image</div>
          </div>
          <div id="controls">controls</div>
          <div id="cta">submit</div>   
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost good, use `max-height:100%` and also add `display:flex` that will give the `height:100%` effect you are trying to achieve on the `modal_inner`

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#app {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 2em;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
}

#modal { 
  max-height: 100%;  
  display:flex;
  position: relative;
  background-color: pink; 
  overflow: hidden;
}

#modal_inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  /*height: 100%; remove this*/
  padding: 2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#image {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  flex: 1;
}

#image .inner {
  background-color: lime;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

#controls {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 20em;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

#cta {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 10em;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  
  <div id="container">
    <div id="modal">
      <div id="modal_inner">
          <div id="title">TITLE</div>
          <div id="image"> 
            <div class="inner">image</div>
          </div>
          <div id="controls">controls</div>
          <div id="cta">submit</div>   
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: @MarsAndBack -- I would recommend to not overuse properties like `display: flex` for simple tasks as center a text. It initiate a lot more work for the browser than necessary. No need in e.g. your `submit` element. And the _height: 100% effect_ you look for (when using flexbox) is briefly explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46956430/2827823

Comment: You're right; I will look out for that. I do often invoke flex centering instinctively.