# How to utilize default stretch property on flex box?

Tags: flexbox

I have these simple flexbox containers and items. I just want them to stretch either across the main axis for flexbox row and column but the default stretch property doesn't seem to work.

```css
.container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.item1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.container2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <input type="text" class="item1" placeholder="placeholder"/>
</div>
<div class="container2">
  <textarea class="item2"></textarea>
</div>
```

According to this answer: [How to stretch flex child to fill height of the container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46954952/how-to-stretch-flex-child-to-fill-height-of-the-container) it should work but I'm not sure why the default stretch is not working.

Am I utilizing `flex-grow` incorrectly here?

Comment: Are you using plain (html, css)? cause in that case, you have to write class attribute as `class`, instead of `className`

Comment: I am! I had no idea. Let me try that

Comment: Ah wait, I forgot, I'm using React

Comment: It seems like main axis works, but cross axis doesn't expand

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a best practice but setting `height:100vh` works for the column oriented flexbox.

```css
.container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.item1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.container2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <input type="text" class="item1" placeholder="placeholder"/>
</div>
<div class="container2">
  <textarea class="item2"></textarea>
</div>
```